# Finding Files in File Tree Based on List of Extensions

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on a small python 3 utility to build a zip file based on a list of file extensions. I have a text file of extensions and I'm passing a folder into the script:

```
working_folder = sys.argv[1]
zip_name = sys.argv[2]

#Open the extension file
extensions = []
with open('CxExt.txt') as fp:
    lines = fp.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        extensions.append(line)

#Now get the files in the directory. If they have the right exttension add them to the list.
files = os.listdir(working_folder)
files_to_zip = []

for ext in extensions:
    results = glob.glob(working_folder + '**/' + ext, recursive=True)
    print(str(len(results)) + " results for " + working_folder + '**/*' + ext)
    #search = "*"+ext
    #results = [y for x in os.walk(working_folder) for y in glob(os.path.join(x[0], search))]
    #results = list(Path(".").rglob(search))
    for result in results:
        files_to_zip.append(result)


if len(files_to_zip) == 0:
    print("No Files Found")
    sys.exit()
for f in files:
    print("Checking: " + f)
    filename, file_extension = os.path.splitext(f)
    print(file_extension)
    if file_extension in extensions:
        print(f)
        files_to_zip.append(file)

ZipFile = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_name, "w" )

for z in files_to_zip:
    ZipFile.write(os.path.basename(z), compress_type=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
```

I've tried using glob, os.walk, and Path.rglob and I still can't get a list of files. There's got to be something just obvious that I'm missing. I built a test directory that has some directories, py files, and a few zip files. It returns 0 for all file types. What am I overlooking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my first answer, so please don't expect it to be perfect.

I notice you're using file.readlines(). According to the Python docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html), file.readlines() returns a list of lines **including the newline at the end**. If your text file has the extensions separated by newlines, maybe try using file.read().split("\n") instead. Besides that, your code looks okay. Tell me if this fix doesn't work.

Comment: Yep that was it. The newline was throwing off the search. Thanks!